# Laravel 5.2 - Populate select options from database

Tags: php, laravel, html-select

Trying to populate the dropdownlist from database. but there having some complication. Any help? This is based on laravel framework.

Part of the code

```
$projects = DB::table('projects')->where('users_id','=',Auth()->User()->id)->get();

                        foreach($projects as $project){
                            echo '
                                    <option value="<?php $id = $project[id] ?>" name="parentProj">'
                                        .$projectName = $project[id].
                                    '</option>
                                  ';
                        }
```

Controller

```
public function index(){
    $projects = DB::table('projects')->lists('id','projectName');

    return view('pages.todo', ['projects'=> $projects);
}
```

Comment: What are the complications you are having? Also, is there a reason you're using plain PHP and not Blade for your view? Blade makes the code easier to both read and write and there are less chances that you'll get a quote, dot or semi colon in the wrong place and mess it all up.

Comment: Also, you have a missing ] in your controller. Should be `['projects'=> $projects]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your view:

```
<select name="parentProj">
    @foreach($projects as $project)
     <option value="{{ $project->id }}">{{ $project->projectName}}</option>
    @endforeach
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Or you can use the Forms & HTML package from Laravel Collective:
https://laravelcollective.com/docs/5.2/html#drop-down-lists

```
{{ Form::select('Projects', $projects)) }}
```